# Delphi XE2 Indy10 udp client-server interchange using SendBuffer-ReceiveBuffer

Tags: udp, indy10

I use Delphi XE2 and Indy10 UDP protocol. 
I can't receive server echo on client side if I use ReceiveBuffer method.
I got "Socket Error # 10040" although I send back very small echo 
message from server to client.
Console application to illustrate my problem is below. 
Thanks in advance.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, IdGlobal, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdSocketHandle,
  IdUDPClient, IdUDPServer, IdUDPBase, IdStack;

type
  TUDP_Serv = class(TIdUDPServer)
    procedure udpSvUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
      AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
  end;
var
  udpServer: TUDP_Serv;
  udpCl: TIdUDPClient;
  bSnd, bRcv: TBytes;
  s: string;
  k: integer;
//==============================================================================
procedure TUDP_Serv.udpSvUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; AData: TIdBytes;
  ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
writeln(' Server read: ' + ToHex(AData, length(AData)));
with ABinding do SendTo(PeerIP, PeerPort, AData);
end;
//==============================================================================
begin
try
  udpServer := TUDP_Serv.Create;
  with udpServer do begin
    OnUDPRead := udpSvUDPRead; DefaultPort := 20001; BufferSize := 2048;
    ThreadedEvent := true; Active := True;
    if Active then writeln('Server started on port: ' + IntToStr(DefaultPort));
  end;
  udpCl := TIdUDPClient.Create;
  with udpCl do begin
    BufferSize := 2048; Host := '127.0.0.1'; Port := 20001;
  end;
  SetLength(bSnd, 5); bSnd[0] := $31; bSnd[1] := $0;
  bSnd[2] := $33; bSnd[3] := $0; bSnd[4] := $0;
  repeat
    writeln(' Client send: ' + ToHex(bSnd, length(bSnd)));
    with udpCl do SendBuffer(Host, Port, bSnd); sleep(100);
    try
      k := udpCl.ReceiveBuffer(bRcv, 10);
      if k > 0 then writeln(' Client read: ' + ToHex(bRcv, length(bRcv)));
    except
      on E: exception do begin
        writeln(Format(' Client read err: %s',[E.Message]));
      end;
    end;
    readln(s);
  until s <> '';
except
  on E: Exception do begin
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message); readln(s);
  end;
end;
end.
```

Screen output:

```
Server started on prot: 20001
 Client send: 3100330000
 Server read: 3100330000
Client read err: Socket Error # 10040
Message too long.
```

Answer (score 0):

10040 is `WSAEMSGSIZE`, which means the buffer you tried to receive into was smaller than the actual size of the message that was received.

You are not allocating any memory for `bRcv` before calling `ReceiveBuffer()`, so you are trying to receive into a 0-byte buffer, hense the error.  You need to pre-allocate `bRcv` to at least the same size as your messages, if not larger.

`ReceiveBuffer()` does not allocate a new `TBytes` for each received message.  You have to allocate the buffer yourself beforehand and then `ReceiveBuffer()` will merely fill it in, returning how many bytes were actually received into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. Unfortunately in Delphi help where is no info about memory allocation for this function while  ReceiveString "create temporary TIdBytes variable".

Comment: `bRcv` is a dynamic array of bytes.  Simple `SetLength()` to allocate it, just like you do with `bSnd`.  `ReceiveString()` uses an internal `TIdBytes` local variable that is allocated to the size specified by the `TIdUDPBase.BufferSize` property before calling `ReceiveBuffer()` to fill in that `TIdBytes`, then the contents of the `TIdBytes` are converted to a `String`.